# li element not acting like others in carousel with thumbnails

Tags: html

Hey guys sorry I have to ask but I can't figure it out. Im using a carousel with thumbnail imgs when clicked the slide and captions auto update one li item is not working like the rest **sliding in the opposite direction** and displaying the wrong caption, **specifically it will display the data-slide-0 caption instead of number data-slide-10** (numbering starts at zero). Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

HTML for the slide caption:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="slider">

<div class="col-md-12" id="carousel-bounding-box">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- main slider carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0" id="slide_0">
        <div class="carousel-caption"><p>The 12-acre campus is located near downtown Seattle bordered by Seattle Center and two major roads.</p>
        <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
        </div>

      </div>
        <div class="item" data-slide-number="1" id="slide_1">
          <div class="carousel-caption"><p>The design concept expresses complementary principles of global mission and local roots through a layering of landscape and buildings. global mission and express the Foundation’s aspirations, while the local ground reconnects the site to the city and provides a community for employees.</p>
          <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
          </div>

        </div>
          <div class="item" data-slide-number="2" id="slide_2">
            <div class="carousel-caption"><p>Prior to construction the site was a 12-acre surface parking lot on a contaminated ground near downtown Seattle.</p>
            <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
            </div>

          </div>
            <div class="item" data-slide-number="3" id="slide_3">
              <div class="carousel-caption"><p>Phase One construction is shown shortly after completion. The campus design turns a historic void into a green urban anchor.</p>
              <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
              </div>

            </div>
              <div class="item" data-slide-number="4" id="slide_4">
                <div class="carousel-caption"><p>Surrounding streetscapes and campus edges provide opportunities for public engagement. Campus materials and planting palette extends out to the street and security barriers are integrated into the benches and seat-walls.</p>
                <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
                </div>

              </div>
                <div class="item" data-slide-number="5" id="slide_5">
                  <div class="carousel-caption"><p>A deep pool and floating central plaza mark the heart of the campus and offer a shared ground to link individual campus buildings.</p>
                  <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                  <div class="item" data-slide-number="6" id="slide_6">
                    <div class="carousel-caption"><p>For employees, the boardwalks that connect to the central plaza provide opportunities for serendipitous meetings en route between buildings.</p>
                    <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="7" id="slide_7">
                      <div class="carousel-caption"><p>Densely planted “local ground” provides a most intimate setting at the water’s edge. Since moving into the new campus, employees have found that using the outdoor workspaces increases productivity and improves their personal health.</p>
                      <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                      <div class="item" data-slide-number="8" id="slide_8">
                      <div class="carousel-caption"><p>The design of the central rainwater pool is inspired by the bogs that once covered this region. The striking contrast between the dark water and the glowing planted edge frames the central space.</p>
                      <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                      <div class="item" data-slide-number="9" id="slide_9">
                      <div class="carousel-caption"><p>To enhance the sense of being grounded on a site that is actually over structure, the design conveys the illusion of thick, dark earth underfoot, with natural textures of salvaged and domestically sourced paving stones.</p>
                      <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="10" id="slide_10">
                      <div class="carousel-caption"><p>Custom formliners were used on the faces of dark concrete retaining walls at water edges and along sidewalks to abstractly imply cuts through a dense slab of moist, peaty ground.</p>
                      <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="11" id="slide_11">
                      <div class="carousel-caption"><p>The landscape is instrumental in achieving the client’s primary goal of building a campus that supports their employees’ productivity. Because many employees travel extensively, a daily connection to light, weather, and seasonal change is essential.</p>
                      <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="12" id="slide_12">
                      <div class="carousel-caption"><p>Nearly 100% of rainwater from non-pollutant generating hard surfaces in the campus is collected into a rainwater cistern below the central courtyard that conserves up to 2 million gallons of water annually.</p>
                      <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="13" id="slide_13">
                      <div class="carousel-caption"><p>Since opening, birds have returned to the area, including multiple families of nesting ducks and a Great Blue Heron that regularly visits, to the delight of employees.</p>
                      <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="item" data-slide-number="14" id="slide_14">
                      <div class="carousel-caption"><p>The aspirations of the largest philanthropic foundation in the world hold that every person, regardless of circumstance, should have the chance to live a healthy, productive life. This ethic is evident throughout the project – from ecologically sensitive systems to streetscapes.</p>
                      <div class="photo-credit"><p>Timothy Hursley, Sean Airhart (NBBJ)</p></div>
                      </div>

                    </div>

    </div>
```

HTML for the slide thumb:

```
      <div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs">

        <!-- thumb navigation carousel items -->
      <ul class="list-inline">
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=one" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=two" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=three" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=four" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li><a id="carousel-selector-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=five" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-5">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=six" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=seven" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-7">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=eight" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-8">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=nine" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-9">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=ten" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-10">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=eleven" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-11">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=twelve" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-12">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=thirteen" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-13">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=fourteen" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-14">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=fifteen" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      </ul>

</div>
```

JS:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 13000
   });

  // handles the carousel thumbnails
   $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
    var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
    var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
    id = parseInt(id);
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
 });

   // when the carousel slides, auto update
   $('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
    var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
    id = parseInt(id);
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
 });

  // auto update the text
  $('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
            var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
            $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
    });
```

Comment: which carousel are you using? and can you provide the js too

Comment: Sure Pete, updated above. Im using a bootstrap carousel btw.